# Javascript in Typescript

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, bootstrap-4

Actually every Javascript code should also be valid in typescript but when I try to run the code below I get the error below. Can someone write this javascript code in typescript?

```
Error: 20: 9 - error TS2531: Object is possibly 'zero'.20 document.getElementById ("navbar"). Style.top = "0";
```

component.ts

```
var prevScrollpos = window.pageYOffset;
    window.onscroll = function() {
    var currentScrollPos = window.pageYOffset;
      if (prevScrollpos > currentScrollPos) {
        document.getElementById("navbar").style.top = "0";
      } else {
        document.getElementById("navbar").style.top = "-50px";
      }
      prevScrollpos = currentScrollPos;
    }
```

html:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark pb_navbar pb_scrolled-light w3-animate-right navlist-right  "  id="navbar">
  <div class="container">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html"></a> 
    <button class="navbar-toggler d-block d-sm-none"   (click)="toggleNavbar()" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#probootstrap-navbar" aria-controls="probootstrap-navbar" aria-expanded="true" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span> 
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse "  [ngClass]="{ 'show': navbarOpen }" id="onright">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#" (click)= " NavBar()" >Home </a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#service" (click)= " NavBar()">Service</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#blog" (click)= " NavBar()">Blog</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#contact" (click)= " NavBar()">Contact</a></li>        
      </ul>
    </div>
    
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: You might have set your tsconfig to be strict. You can set it to be very loose and let all errors pass. But maybe if you say `document.getElementById("navbar")!.style.top = "0";` (i.e. putting an exclamation mark there) it might work, though i haven't tried it

Comment: You could do `document.getElementById("navbar")?.style.top` or do something like `var navbar = document.getElementById("navbar")` then do an if statement based on `navbar`. Something like `if (navbar != null) { navbar.style.top = 0; }`

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you that you may have a run-time error, since `document.getElementById("navbar")` may return null so `document.getElementById("navbar").style.top` may throw an error if the element doesn't exist.
If you are OK with it, you can either add inline exceptions or switch your typescript configuration to non-strict mode.

link: [strict](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#strict)

Answer (score 0):

For this try to wrap the
document.getElementById("navbar")
With its type and then you can also use safe navigator which is ? To navigate only if the earlier object is not null

Answer (score 0):

The Solution:

component.ts:

```
import { Inject }  from '@angular/core';
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/common'; 

constructor(@Inject(DOCUMENT) document){}

 prevScrollpos = window.pageYOffset;
  @HostListener('window:scroll', ['$event'])
  onWindowScroll() {
  var currentScrollPos = window.pageYOffset;
    if (this.prevScrollpos > currentScrollPos) {
        window.document.getElementById('navbar')!.style.top = "0";
      } else if (this.prevScrollpos < currentScrollPos) {
        window.document.getElementById('navbar')!.style.top = "-50px";
      }
      this.prevScrollpos = currentScrollPos;
    }
```

tsconfig.json

add this line to compilerOptions:

```
"noImplicitAny": false,
```